# How to set up separate confirmation email and website url for same mailchimp form when the form is submitted from different websites

Tags: forms, mailchimp, confirmation, email-confirmation

We have mailchimp list and is linked to different forms on the website i.e. different pages.
Is there a way we can setup the different confirmation email and thank you page link when submitted from different pages i.e. when the form is submitted from contact show different confirmation email  message and thank you url when the subscription is confirmed and when the form is submitted from about us page let's say then separate email message and thank you url after the subscription confirmation.